# set the title of an html page using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, web, frontend

A title of an page is set by external javascript. I cannot find the exact function which does it. So i wrote a function and placed it in the html file. But still it is showing title of the previous javascript function.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {
    document.title = 'Pry';
});

 </script>
```

Comment: `Object.defineProperty(document,'title',{set:function(){throw new Error();}})` should tell you where it's being set by other code by throwing an error when it tries to do so.

Comment: You could also try a MutationObserver https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll be best listening for a change, if possible, in your use case.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("title", "head").change(function () {
      console.log("Title has changed");
      changeTitle();
  });

  //Trigger Change
  function changeTitle() {
      $("title", "head").text("New Title");
  }

  $("title","head").text("test Title").trigger('change'); // triggered elsewhere
});
```

Comment: External script won't trigger `change`.

Comment: Oh crud. Didn't think about this you know... useful to leave here for anyone on a similar track I guess.

Answer (score 2):

You can also attempt to change title periodically. As you don't knows when scripts actually changes the title.

```
setInterval(function() {
   document.title = 'Pry';
}, 1000);
```

If script changes title once, you can also stop this timer once title is changed

```
var title = 'Pry';
var count = 0;
var timer = setInterval(function() {

    if (document.title !== title)
       count += 1;

    document.title = title;

    // count will be incremented twice
    // once when this function runs for first time
    // when title is actually changed
    if (count >= 2)
        clearInterval(timer);

}, 1000);
```

It will be better you edit script that is actually changing the title instead of writing another routine to change the title.

Comment: Don't think it will work. You set the title to 'Pry' than you check if `document.title === title` and you conclude it changed? It did not change at all, it was and remained 'Pry'.

Comment: I am not able to find the script which is changing it. The javascript is too long.

Comment: @skobaljic I've modified. Hope so that will better detect title is actually changed.